# Mapping table of objects to java dataype on different schemas

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have on my databse instance a table of objects created like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_PWServiceWebreport
AS OBJECT (
            ELEMENTNAME  VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,AFFECTEDAS   VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,SERVICENAME  VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,SEVICETYPE   VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,STATUSCODE   VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,SUBSCRIBER   VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,SITEID       VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,SITEFULLNAME VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,ROUTE        VARCHAR2 (1000)
           ,THIRDPARTY   VARCHAR2 (1000)
           )

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_PWServiceWebreport AS TABLE OF O_PWServiceWebreport
```

And there is also a procedure that puts in some output param results of type `T_PWServiceWebreport` .

Now I need to get this results into a java variable by calling this procedure.
This is my code:

```
Connection oConnection = null;
    Statement nodeTypeQuery = null;
    CallableStatement procedureCallStatement = null;
    Driver myDriver = null;
    String getServiceByObjAndDimObj = "{call pkgcomsupport_service.process_PWservices(?,?)}";
    try{
        myDriver = (Driver)Class.forName("weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver").newInstance(); 
        oConnection = myDriver.connect("datasource", null);
        procedureCallStatement = oConnection.prepareCall(getServiceByObjAndDimObj);
        procedureCallStatement.setString(1, objectId);
        procedureCallStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY);
        procedureCallStatement.executeUpdate(); 
        Object[] rs = (Object[])((Array)procedureCallStatement.getObject(2)).getArray();
        for(Object tmp: rs){
            Struct row = (Struct) tmp;
            request.setAttribute("rs", tmp);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        request.setAttribute("rs", ex.getMessage());
      }
      finally{
        try {  
            procedureCallStatement.close();
            procedureCallStatement = null;
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        try { 
            oConnection.close();
            oConnection = null; 
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
```

My error in this case is

> ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

Adding the name of the plsql collection as a parameter to `registerOutParameter` raises:

> java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: cramer_common.T_PWServiceWebreport

I think this is because the plsql collection is defined on a different schema, same schema as the procedure but different from the caller one as seen in above error message.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should set your array name as

```
procedureCallStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "T_PWServiceWebreport");
```